# How to make a windows phone application load faster like default applications?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I've observed that the default applications like People, Calculator.etc in Windows phones don't take time to load at all. They don't even have a Splash Screen image. I've tried excluding the SplashScreenImage.jpg from the project in my applications and run it on my phone, my application is static & just displays texts and still it takes time to load, why is it so? How can I make my applications to function like the default windows applications without waiting time and no SplashScreen images?

Comment: this could be useful : http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/03/25/ways-to-load-applications-faster-a-windows-phone-recipe.aspx

Comment: Also helpful: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/04/03/optimize-startup-time.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windows Phone 7**

On Windows Phone 7 it's not possible to make a 3rd party app perform like the built-in apps such as People, Pictures, Calendar, Games, Music+Videos, etc.

Those apps are mostly likely written in C++ and are natively compiled, have special permission to run in the background (so they resume instantly), and have full OS/hardware access.

3rd party apps (ie. the apps you and I can write) are compiled against the Silverlight platform which is not as performant as natively compiled C++ code, which is why even a simple app with no splash screen and a single `TextBlock` will take longer to load than, say, the built-in Games app (and not feature the proper entrance animation).

So, all you can do is try and make your app startup as fast as possible, given the circumstances. There are 2 great links mentioned in the comments above and I'll add one more...

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/windows-phone-performance/

(It's from 2010 but the advice is still valid)

**Windows Phone 8**

Performance is a lot better on Windows Phone 8. Even an existing WP7 app will startup and run faster. But if you're starting a new app targeting WP8 only, then app startup is almost instant and you will get the proper 'entrance animation' when using the built-in `Pivot` and `Panorama` controls.

**Which platform?**

When choosing which version of Windows Phone to develop for and support, it helps to have real data to make your decision. Ad Duplex recently published some stats from a set of popular apps that run their ads on Windows Phone...

http://blog.adduplex.com/2013/09/adduplex-windows-phone-statistics.html

As you can see, Windows Phone 8 does make up the share of devices (up to 78%) in some markets, so it may be easier to start with WP8 - and you would definitely have less performance issues to worry about!