# Window Phone8:Black screen after splash screen

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I have been facing this issue for quite a long time now.The problem is that i am getting the blackscreen after my app loads the SplashScreenImage.jpg.The blackscreen remaims for 4 to 5 seconds and then my app loads the landing page.

i tried using some plugin for splashscreen
Also used the `navigator.splashscreen.show()` and `hide` methods of the plugin but was unable to achieve any success.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

I literally searched for more than two days about getting this black-screen issue resolved.
Finally after not getting any proper solution from the web i decided to dig in the issue and solve it.

So here is the solution

just add  the following lines to your MainPage.xaml

```
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="yoursplashimage.jpg"/>
```

So now your MainPage.xaml should some what look like following

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="yourappsnamespace.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
Background="Black"
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480" 
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPCordovaClassLib">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="yoursplashimage.jpg"/>
    <my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Margin="0,0,0,0"  
               x:Name="CordovaView" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

That's it.Now you will get rid of the dumb blackscreen.
One more thing just remove the SplashScreenImage.jpg from the root folder to avoid flickering of images(Note: Its ok if you don't remove the SplashScreenImage.jpg it depends upon once choice)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could remove or reduce the time of that black screen appearing  right after the `Splashscreen`. 
But you could try making your app more faster which could ideally load your app quicker.
[Ways to Load Applications Faster](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173091/Ways-to-Load-Applications-Faster-A-Windows-Phone-R)

Reference: [How to make a windows phone application load faster like default applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710740/)

Comment: Hi actually i tried your way but its not working.There has to be some easy way out.can u please help me out with other solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do if **you're using the SplashScreen just for the branding purpose.**

Create a new page.

Set the SplashScreen Image as the background image of this page.

On the Load Event, say LayoutRoot Load Event, add some delay

After the delay time is over Navigate to your MainPage.

The code is somewhat like:-

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;  //add the namespace
    private async void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);   //add the delay
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/StartingPage.xaml"));  //navigate to your starting page
    }
```